# Assign a value to an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm currently working on a text editor. I have an entire GUI working, and now I'm trying to add usability to it.

For some reason, when I try to create an array called symbols, NetBeans is fine with it -- when I try to assign a value to the array, NetBeans won't compile my program, and will instead give an error and suggest it make a new class for the array.

Example code:

```
String[] symbols = new String[42]; symbols[0] = "∑"; // Error line!
```

Here's an image: http://img401.imageshack.us/img401/4844/examplegx.png

Does anyone know the solution to fix this or has this happened to you? If I need to provide more detail, let me know.

Answer (score 8):

You're trying to put an arbitrary statement directly in your class declaration, instead of in a method, constructor or initializer block. You can't do that.

Some options:

- Do it in the constructor:

  ```
  public GUI()
  {
      symbols[0] = "∑";
  }
  ```
- Do it in an initializer block:

  ```
  String[] symbols = new String[42]; 
  {
      symbols[0] = "∑";
  }
  ```
- Do it in a method called by the initializer:

  ```
  String[] symbols = getDefaultSymbols();

  private static String[] getDefaultSymbols()
  {
      String[] ret = new String[42];
      ret[0] = "∑";
      return ret;
  }
  ```
- Use an array initializer:

  ```
  String[] symbols = { "∑", null, null, null, ... };
  ```

Note that your question is phrased as if Netbeans were to blame. It's not Netbeans - it's the Java language rules. Your code wouldn't be valid under Eclipse, javac, IntelliJ etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, this code worked for my program.

Comment: This is a good example as it shows the use of a function call to initialize a value, few people know this is possible.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot place code outside a method or initializer block. What you can do is;

```
String[] symbols = new String[42]; { symbols[0] = "∑"; }
```

You can also define your symbols this way

```
String[] symbols = "∑,+,-,/,*,^".split(",");
```